# Relationship between weights in the minimization of a weighted average and the slopes of the function at the optimum

Tags: calculus, optimization

Following ideas in Meta on reposting a question, I add below a corrected version of my query. The original version got a correct answer but it does not apply to the corrected version.

## Introduction

Let $f(q)$ be a $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ convex function and consider the minimisation problem

$$\min\quad w q +(1-w)f(q)$$

for some $w\in\left[0,1\right[$. The FOC for this problem is $w+(1-w)\frac{d f(q)}{dq}=0$. As a consequence, solving this problem for a given $w$ is equivalent to finding $q$ such that the slope of the function is equal to $-\frac{w}{1-w}$. The following example suggests this is also true in higher dimensions.

### Example:

Imagine that we are looking for the point on a sphere such that the slopes are $-\frac{5}{3}$ and $-\frac{5}{7}$. First we need to determine the appropriate $w$, so we solve

\begin{align*}
\frac{w_1}{w_2}&=\frac{5}{3}\\
\frac{w_1}{w_3}&=\frac{5}{7}\\
w_1+w_2+w_3&=1
\end{align*}

i.e., $w_1=\frac{1}{3}$, $w_2=\frac{1}{5}$ and $w_3=\frac{7}{15}$. The solution to
\begin{align*}
\min&\;\frac{x_1}{3}+\frac{x_2}{5}+\frac{7x_3}{15}\\
s.t.&\;(x_1-1)^2+(x_2-1)^2+(x_3-1)^2=1
\end{align*}

is $x^*=(1-\frac{5}{\sqrt{83}},1-\frac{3}{\sqrt{83}},1-\frac{7}{\sqrt{83}})$ and $\lambda^*=\frac{\sqrt{83}}{30}$.

As we have an explicit formula for the sphere, we can compute

\begin{align*}
   \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1}=-\frac{1-x_1}{\sqrt{1-(x_1-1)^2-(x_3-1)^2}}\\
   \frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_1}=-\frac{1-x_1}{\sqrt{1-(x_1-1)^2-(x_2-1)^2}}
\end{align*}

and, substituting the value $x^*$, we get
\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_1}\right|_{x=x^*}&=-\frac{5}{3}=-\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{5}}=-\frac{w_1}{w_2}\\
\left.\frac{\partial x_3}{\partial x_1}\right|_{x=x^*}&=-\frac{5}{7}=-\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{7}{15}}=-\frac{w_1}{w_3}
\end{align*}

as expected.

## Original question

I'm having a hard time generalising this intuition to an implicit $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ function. Specifically, I have $m$ functions $x_j=f_j(q)$, with $q\in\Bbb R^n$. I'm trying to show that solving

\begin{align*}
\min&\sum_{j=1}^m w_j f_j(q)\\
s.t.&\sum_{i=1}^n q_i=1
\end{align*}

for some $w$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^m w_j=1$ and $w_j\geq 0\;\forall j$ is tantamount to finding the $q^*$ such that $\left.\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_{j'}}\right|_{q=q^*}=-\frac{w_{j'}}{w_j}.$ I don't know whether this is relevant, but in my case $f_j(q)\geq 0\;\forall j\;\forall q\geq0$.

The FOCs for this problem are
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m w_{j}\frac{df_{j}(q)}{d q_i}-\lambda=0\;\forall i=\{1,\dots,n\},
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier associated to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^nq_i=1$. If $\forall i$, $w_{j^*}\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_{i}}\neq 0$, we can write
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{\frac{df_{j}(q)}{d q_i}}{\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\frac{w_{j}}{w_{j^*}}=\frac{\lambda}{w_{j^*}\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\;\forall i=\{1,\dots,n\}.
$$

My questions are:

1. Am I right identifying $\left.\frac{\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{d q_i}}{\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\right |_{q=q^*}=\left.\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{df_{j^{*}}(q)}\right |_{q=q^*}$? Is this an instance of implicit differentiation?
2. How can I prove that $\left.\frac{\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{d q_i}}{\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\right |_{q=q^*}=-\frac{w_{j^*}}{w_{j^\star}}$?

## Corrected version

I'd like to generalise this intuition to an implicit $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ function. Specifically, I have $m$ **strictly convex, distinct** functions $x_j=f_j(q)$, with $q\in\Bbb R^n$. I believe the claim to be true for strictly convex functions, but for my purposes it would suffice to show it to be true for $f_j(q)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} q_i^{\alpha_i}$ with $a_{ij}\geq 0\;\forall i,j$ and $\alpha_i>1\;\forall i$ (or, even, $\alpha_i=\alpha>1\;\forall i$). Also, let $A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i \leq n,1\leq j \leq m}$ and assume $\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}\rank A=m$ (In the proposed solution to the previous wording of the question $\rank A=1<m=2$). I'm trying to show that solving

\begin{align*}
\min&\sum_{j=1}^m w_j f_j(q)\\
s.t.&\sum_{i=1}^n q_i=1
\end{align*}

for some $w$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^m w_j=1$ and $w_j\geq 0\;\forall j$ is tantamount to finding the $q^*$ such that $\left.\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_{j'}}\right|_{q=q^*}=-\frac{w_{j'}}{w_j}.$ As $=-\frac{w_{j'}}{w_j}\in(0,-\infty)$, this requires that the slopes of the function take any value in that range too. This is true in the sphere example and it is also satisfied in the case of my polynomial functions (and this is why we need $\rank A=m$). I don't know whether this is relevant, but in my case $f_j(q)\geq 0\;\forall j\;\forall q\geq0$.

The FOCs for this problem are
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m w_{j}\frac{df_{j}(q)}{d q_i}-\lambda=0\;\forall i=\{1,\dots,n\},
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier associated to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^nq_i=1$. If $\forall i$, $w_{j^*}\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_{i}}\neq 0$, we can write
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{\frac{df_{j}(q)}{d q_i}}{\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\frac{w_{j}}{w_{j^*}}=\frac{\lambda}{w_{j^*}\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\;\forall i=\{1,\dots,n\}.
$$

### My questions are:

1. Am I right identifying $\left.\frac{\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{d q_i}}{\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\right |_{q=q^*}=\left.\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{df_{j^{*}}(q)}\right |_{q=q^*}$? Is this an instance of implicit differentiation?
2. How can I prove that $\left.\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{df_{j^{*}}(q)}\right |_{q=q^*}=-\frac{w_{j^*}}{w_{j^\star}}$?

### Example (and, perhaps, answer to question $1$)

Let $x_1=2q_1^2+q_2^2$ and $x_2=q_1^2+2q_2^2$. As $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 1\\ 1 & 2\end{array}\right)$ and $\rank A=2$, these functions satisfy the requirements of the question. We can compute

$$\frac{\frac{df_{2}(q)}{d q_1}}{\frac{df_{1}(q)}{d q_1}}=\frac{2q_1}{4q_1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

which is obviously wrong as $\frac{d x_2}{d x_1}$ is not constant. The problem stems from disregarding the role of the constraint $q_1+q_2=1$. If we use it in $x_1,x_2$ so $f_1^{c_1}=2q_1^2+(1-q_1)^2$ and $f_2^{c_1}=q_1^2+2(1-q_1)^2$, we can obtain

$$\frac{\frac{df^{c_1}_{2}(q)}{d q_1}}{\frac{df^{c_1}_{1}(q)}{d q_1}}=\frac{6q_1-4}{6q_1-2}$$

Let $s=\frac{6q_1-4}{6q_1-2}$ and observe that $s\leq 0\implies q_1\in\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$. If we choose $w\geq 0$ and my guess is correct, $q_1$ needs to be in that interval, as $-\frac{w_1}{w_2}\leq 0$. Choose, for instance, $w=\left(\frac{7}{11},\frac{4}{11}\right)$. The solution to the corresponding minimisation problem is $q_1=\frac{5}{11}\in\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$. Note further that

$$s=\frac{6\frac{5}{11}-4}{6\frac{5}{11}-2}=-\frac{7}{4}=-\frac{w_1}{w_2}.$$

Taking the derivative with respect to $q_1$ or $q_2$ is immaterial: Let $f_1^{c_2}=2(1-q_2)^2+q_2^2$ and $f_2^{c_2}=(1-q_2)^2+2q_2^2$. As $\frac{\frac{df^{c_2}_{2}(q)}{d q_2}}{\frac{df^{c_2}_{1}(q)}{d q_2}}=\frac{6q_2-2}{6q_2-4}$ it is also the case that

$$\left.\frac{\frac{df_{2}(q)}{d q_1}}{\frac{df_{1}(q)}{d q_1}}\right|_{q=q^*}=\left.\frac{\frac{df^{c_2}_{2}(q)}{d q_2}}{\frac{df^{c_2}_{1}(q)}{d q_2}}\right|_{q=q^*}=-\frac{7}{4}.$$

This example shows that $$\left.\frac{\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{d q_i}}{\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\right |_{q=q^*}\ne \left.\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{df_{j^{*}}(q)}\right |_{q=q^*}.$$

However, it appears that $$\left.\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{df_{j^{*}}(q)}\right |_{q=q^*}=-\frac{w_{j^*}}{w_{j^\star}}$$ can still be true.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is not right. We can find a counter example.

First, in general framework, you want to solve
\begin{align*}
\min&\sum_{j=1}^m w_j f_j(q)\\
s.t.&\sum_{i=1}^n q_i=1
\end{align*}
where $f_j:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. By using Langrange multiplier, you can obtain
$$
\sum_{j=1}^m w_{j}\frac{df_{j}(q^*)}{d q_i}-\lambda=0\,,\quad \forall\ i=\{1,\dots,n\},
$$
where $q^*$ is your possible optimal point, $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier associated to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^nq_i=1$. This implies
$$
\nabla F(q^*)\cdot w=\left[\nabla f_1(q^*)|\nabla f_2(q^*)|\cdots|\nabla f_m(q^*)\right]\cdot w=\lambda \vec{e}\tag{1}
$$
where $\nabla F(q^*)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $\nabla f_i(q^*)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\vec{e}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\vec{e}_k=1$ for all $k$.

Now, I want to give the counter example. Consider $n=m=2$ and $f_1(q)=f_2(q)=|q|^2$. Then, in this case, we always have
$$
\frac{\partial_i f_1}{\partial i f_2}=1\,.
$$
Next, we choose $w_1=\frac{1}{4}, w_2=\frac{3}{4}$, we can still solve this minimization problem. First, (1) implies
$$
(w_1+w_2)q^*_1=\frac{\lambda}{2},\quad (w_1+w_2)q^*_2=\frac{\lambda}{2}\,,
$$
which implies
$$
q^*_1=\frac{\lambda}{2},\quad q^*_2=\frac{\lambda}{2}\,.
$$

Since we also need constraint $q^*_1+q^*_2=1$, we should choose $\lambda=1$. This implies
$$
q^*_1=q^*_2=\frac{1}{2}
$$
It's obvious that at $q=q^*$
$$
\frac{\partial_i f_1}{\partial i f_2}=1\neq -\frac{w_2}{w_1}
$$
Thus, your guess is not right.

Comment: By $|q|^2$ you mean $q_1^2+q_2^2$?

Comment: I should have asked for $f_j(q)\ne f_{j'}\,\forall j,j'$. In fact, **strict** convexity is needed and slopes of the function (in $\Bbb R^m$) need to be take every value in $(0,\infty)$. Your counter example satisfies strict convexity, but not the second requirement, as it consists of just one point $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and, hence, the slope is not defined (that's why for any $w$ the solution is $q_1=q_2=\frac{1}{2}$). I'm awarding you the bounty as your answer is correct given my faulty question, but I'd be glad to hear your thoughts on my revised claim

Comment: What is the slope of the function? Can you define it strictly?

Comment: I don't know. I was asking whether $\left.\frac{\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{d q_i}}{\frac{df_{j^{*}}(q)}{d q_i}}\right |_{q=q^*}=\left.\frac{df_{j^\star}(q)}{df_{j^{*}}(q)}\right |_{q=q^*}$ in the hope of being able to obtain a definition through the implicit function theorem

Comment: I believe the guess is general, but in my specific case, $f_j(q)$ is polynomial in $q_i$ with exponents $\alpha_i>1$. For instance $n=m=2$, $f_1(q)=2q_1^2+q_2^2$ and $f_2(q)=q_1^2+2q_2^2$

Comment: If we let $x=f_1(q)=2q_1^2+q_2^2$ and $y=f_2(q)=q_1^2+2q_2^2$ and use $1=q_1+q_2$ I think we could write $\frac{d y}{d x}=-\frac{\frac{d y}{d q_1}}{\frac{d x}{d q_1}}=-\frac{6q_1-4}{6q_1-2}$. Note that $q_1=\frac{2}{3}\implies -\frac{6q_1-4}{6q_1-2}=0$ and $\lim_{q_1\to\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{6q_1-4}{6q_1-2}=-\infty$. So, for positive weights $w$ we could obtain any value of the slope in $(0,-\infty)$. Of course, this can only be done if $n=m$. I'm interested in the case $n\geq m$.

Comment: I have revamped significantly the question and added a new bounty. Perhaps you want to take another look at it